# Spring Roo jspx Nightmare... ItemLabel is not enough

Tags: java, jquery, spring-roo, jspx

I got a row in my `create.jspx` as follows:

```
<field:select field="groupsowdrefs" 
              id="c_com_usergroups_manager_domain_Users_groupsowdrefs" 
              itemValue="id" items="${groupsviews}" multiple="true" 
              path="/groupsviews" z="yuLSgZ+z3Zrwet6KAYzGT+xFndc="/>
```

this field displays a box with rows populated by the relationship `@ManyToMany` between 2 entities.

Now the problem is that the first entity has only one `String` attribute which populates this box, but has itself a `@ManytoOne` relation with another entity. This value is important and is not shown in the box rows!

This happens because the `field:select` shows only attributes and not fields of related entities.

I tried to put an `ItemLabel` tag and it works but box rows show only one field at time.

Maybe a simple `div` which shows the info i need on clicking the rows of the box, or a concatenate `ItemLabel`, a jquery trick..or anything..would solve this, but jspx is hard to understand to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to add a getter to the class you want, as a read-only property:

```
public getSelectDescription() {
    // concatenate desired values
}
```

and use that property in the `itemLabel`

```
itemLabel="selectDescription"
```

Comment: i tryied...it gaves me "null"...don't know why...actually i did a String private attribute = this.field1 + " " + this.field2...and create getters and setters...linked to itemlabel..always null...

Comment: morely...in the attempt of a simple method it gaves error: Invalid property 'getSelectDescription()' of bean class [com.usergroups.manager.domain.Groupsview]: Bean property 'getSelectDescription()' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?....otherwise with a field attribute with the linked values , set and get method done, it gaves null as i said before..

Comment: `attribute` is evaluated when `field1`, `field2` have not received values yet, that's why it's null. In the `.jspx` you have to use `selectDescription` as if there was an attribute with that name.

Comment: Great. Sign as Solved! Why anyway that strange practice for the ghost attribute? and...another thing...the box went extralong and goes out of the page!

Comment: You might want to modify the method to restrict the length of the output. Or post a new question with the visual details of the overflow.